# javascript serialize on appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization

Is it possible to serialize appended forms in jquery? I tried both button.on(click) and form.on(submit), but got a problem. When I use the onclick button it gives me an undefined serialization. When I use form submit, it gives me nothing.

Here's my JS Code:

```
function main_login(){

$('.main-login').click(function(){
var adpas = prompt("Enter password: ");
if(adpas !== null){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'init.php',
        data: {data: adpas},
        success: function(data){
    if(data == "success"){
            $('#main-note').css('display', 'initial');
            $('#main-note').append(''+
'<div id="note_app" style="height: 450px; width: 700px; background-color: white; border-radius: 10px;">'+
'<div style="height:12px; width:15px; border-radius:10px; background: linear-gradient(red, white);" align="center"><a href="index.html" onclick="close_window()" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">X</a></div>'+
'<center><form action="" id="formmsg" method="post"><input type="text" id="note-title" style="width: 98%; height: 20px; font-size:16px"/>'+
'<textarea id="note-texts" style="width: 98%; height: 400px; resize: none;"></textarea></center>'+
'<input type="submit" value="Encode Lecture" name="btn-lecture" id="btn-lecture"></form></div>');

    $('#formmsg').on('submit', function() {
        alert($(this).serialize());
    });

    }

    else{
        alert('You don\'t have any administrative rights to open this link.');
    }



        }
    });

}
});

}
```

Another question:
It seems that every time I  successfully click "main-login class", it gives me the same number of divs it is clicked. Is there anyway to make the button trigger only once, only if the password was accepted and successful?

Tried jQuery.one(); it worked but both for successful and failed login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('this')` should be `$(this)`.

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit. that doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are trying to attach an event to an element which was created dynamically! So here `event delegation` helps you and instead of keeping event inside `success` of ajax, which is obviously not a good thing, put it outside! Following will be the changes you need to do!!

```
$('.main-login').click(function(){
   var adpas = prompt("Enter password: ");
   if(adpas !== null){
       $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'init.php',
          data: {data: adpas},
          success: function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
               $('#main-note').css('display', 'initial');
               $('#main-note').append(''+
'<div id="note_app" style="height: 450px; width: 700px; background-color: white; border-radius: 10px;">'+
'<div style="height:12px; width:15px; border-radius:10px; background: linear-gradient(red, white);" align="center"><a href="index.html" onclick="close_window()" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">X</a></div>'+
'<center><form action="" id="formmsg" method="post"><input type="text" id="note-title" style="width: 98%; height: 20px; font-size:16px"/>'+
'<textarea id="note-texts" style="width: 98%; height: 400px; resize: none;"></textarea></center>'+
'<input type="submit" value="Encode Lecture" name="btn-lecture" id="btn-lecture"></form></div>');
             }
             else{
                alert('You don\'t have any administrative rights to open this link.');
             }
         }
       });
    }
});
```

Now your form `submit` event:

```
$('#main-note').on('submit','#formmsg', function() {
    console.log($(this).serialize());
});
```

That should work now.

Comment: Do I need to put a comma between #formmsg' and function()? And where should I put it? outside the $('.main-login') click function? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you do need to put a comma, edited my answer!! and yea put it outside `$('.main-login').click`

Comment: You're right about the event delegation. Thanks for the info. But when I try it, it gives me an error about 'on' is not a function. Tried several suggestions from the net, like bind, delegate, and live, but no luck.

Comment: what version of `jquery` you are using??

Comment: So what changes you've made?